# How to scale points to pixels in different resolutions

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have brandbrook provided, where only information is to use 1,5 pt stroke weight in my illustrations. How to correctly pick my lines stroke weight in pixels in 1920x1080 resolution?

Does it mean that If I had 100x100 resolution, I would need to pick 1,5 px?

Comment: there is no answer to the question. its missing a piece of the puzzle.

Comment: what is this missing puzzle exactly? @joojaa

Comment: there us no way to tell because there is no information on pixel density so there is no pixel to physycal size conversion. Answer is different on every possible viewing device out there

Answer (score 0):

1920x1080 is not the only "resolution" you need.

What you need is "the Pixel density".

If your screen is Full HD (1920x1080px) but is the size of a cellphone, the pixel density will be different than if the screen is a 28-inch monitor.

---

**So the first answer will be:**

Take the horizontal pixels 1920 and divide them by the horizontal measure of the physical device in your case. Let's say a 5-inch cell phone.

1920/5 The pixel density is now 384 pixels for each inch. 384 PPI

One definition of a Pt is 1/72 of an inch. So.

384/72 = 5.33 pixels each Pt.

---

**The second answer is:**

But sometimes there had being some efforts to standardize the "size" of a pixel, or pixel density at least, for example, the undying myth of "72 PPI is for screens". Some time ago the number 96 PPI appeared on more popular Windows systems back when the PC was starting to become a thing.

An effort to standardize CSS pixels is using the same 96 PPI number to make a pixel have a standard physical dimension (which for me is an error, but c'est la vie)

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#absolute-lengths

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)#Desktop_publishing_point

So you can use one of those two numbers.

1 Pt = 1px (Using 72 PPI) 1:1 ratio

1 Pt = 1.33 px (Using 96 PPI) 4:3 ratio